# a CSS file with all the browser incompatibilities sorted out

Tags: css, browser, incompatibility

Has anyone developed a CSS File which has all the major browser quirks sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: @femi, most major websites have, but there is no panacea for browser-compatibility. It's not an easy feat, but takes much effort and time both in page design and CSS styling. Do you have a particular question?

Comment: Browser quirks arise from differences in rendering engine, which I don't believe can be "sorted out" in a generic sense, at least not in pure CSS. It's largely dependent on your use of margins, padding, positioning, etc. - thus, it has to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Where is this magic CSS file? I desire it!

Comment: This mug explains it all... http://www.zazzle.com/css_is_awesome_mug-168716435071981928

Comment: +1 for the question, which was clearly misunderstood.

Comment: One CSS to rule them all, One CSS to find them, One CSS to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Yahoo's [Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a "reset stylesheet." Googling that phrase comes up with any number of usable examples.

I've often used one from the "YUI" framework, discussed here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 1):

A [CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) (this link has many, depending your usage, whether you need uncommon tags as well or just basics) is what you're looking for, which you could furthemore combine with a [CSS Grid](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-960-grid-system-made-easy/)